# Using the ASP.NET OAuth providers without ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

My project is using asp.net membership (not Identity), I am trying to implement the OAuth based on the steps listed at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services)

While testing the code, it created the identity tables at my database (AspNetUsers, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetRoles...)

I don't want to use these tables, I want to use it with the membership tables (aspnet_Users, aspnet_Membership...)

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var applicationUserManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    //while executing this line, the identity tables are created
    var applicationUser = await applicationUserManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
    if (applicationUser == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }

    var claimsIdentityOAuth =
            await applicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(applicationUserManager,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    var claimsIdentityCookie = await applicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(applicationUserManager,
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    var properties = CreateProperties(applicationUser.UserName);
    var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentityOAuth, properties);
    context.Validated(authenticationTicket);
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(claimsIdentityCookie);
}
```

How to use OAuth with asp.net membership?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that but, you need a custom implementation of `Identity` tables and then do a map for your desired tables using `Entity Framework Code First`

[Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("YouUserTableMembership");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("YouUserTableMembership");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("YouUserRoleTableMembership");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("YouUserClaimTableMembership");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("YouUserLoginTableMembership");
    }
```